# Symfony4 editable global app settings for users from backend

Tags: symfony, settings, global, symfony4

**Scenario:**

I want to implement user editable app settings in my symfony application but don't know what's the best practice.

The user should be able to edit global settings like company address or alike in the app backend, no user specific settings.

I had a look at the CraueConfigBundle, but I think a file based settings solution fits more to my problem.

It's difficult to find something on Google for my problem, maybe you can help me find that out.

What do you use to give your app admins the possibility to edit global settings?

Answer (score 0):

For basic CraueConfigBundle can work for you (didn't use it just read docs) even tho it's saving to database.

Do you have particular reason why you need saving into file? You can always set up case to save data from database to file.

But if you want to write something in general, its require few steps like basically like this:

- You need service which provide reading / uploading of configuration
- This service can take use of adapters to do real Saving reading from your chosen source of data (for example you can use symfony Yaml component which can read / dump data from Yaml)
- Then you need write user interface which suits your needs for that